# Hot line impulse >50V and lights flickering off - thoughts on solution?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I have an issue where ceiling LED lights (recessed or ceiling fan) will either momentarily shut off or go bright and then shut off before recovering shortly thereafter - it also impacts the ceiling fan motor if spinning.  I don't know if it's multiple locations in the house at once, but I know it's not all locations at once, though it is all lights which are together on the same switch simultaneously.  The different locations are different bulb brands across different circuits and switch types (dumb rocker, ELV non-smart dimmer, and ELV smart dimmer) and switch brands.

Based on reading on this site I suspected the power is not clean, so I bought the Powertronics Probe 100+ and after it being plugged in, soon it registered an impulse on the hot line of >20V and later on one over 50V.

Is this probably the cause?  Thoughts on how I should go about trying to solve it?

If I wanted to go all out, I can hook this up to USB and record/watch the sine wave over time and compare to when the lights have issues but I'm wondering if this is already something I should fix regardless and just see if it solves it.

Comment: Have an accomplice go into the bathroom and turn a hair dryer on and off every 20 seconds or so. Do all the lights in the house act wacky when they do?  Do you have a voltmeter? Can you check random receptacle voltages around the house?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica the hair dryer seems to have no impact on any lights.  I checked several receptacle voltages around the house and they all read 124V +- 1V

Comment: OK, that crosses off a common reason, a lost neutral. (disconnection of neutral from utility can make it very prone to voltage swings due to loads).